# VS 2013 Sign In Error on OldConvergedLogin_PCore.js

Tags: visual-studio-2013, signing

I logged out of my Visual Studio 2013. Now when I log in it shows me input for email and when I enter email and click next it shows me script error saying `permission denied on https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.27868.00/OldConvergedLogin_PCore.js`
I click on run script `yes` but then the login screen goes blank white for hours and nothing happened.

I have `VS 2017` also. And `VS Code 2017`. The Problem arises when I try to run command `Team:Signin` in `Visual Studio Source Control Extention` of VS Code 2017.

P.S. I am successfully login in `VS2017`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the error by updating IE Version to 11